# Curious Mixin with variadic constructor

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, mixins, crtp, injected-class-name

I have a code snipped including a variadic mixin crtp of some sorts and a few related questions. Do I understand correctly that in the following code, the second constructor is merely passing copies of instances of those classes which were used to instantiate X to the constructors of those very same classes?

```
template<class DerivedT>
struct CuriousBase{};

template<template<typename> typename... Features>
struct X : Features<X<Features...>> ... {
  X() = default;
  X(Features<X<Features...>> ...f) : Features<X<Features...>>(f)... {}
};

int main(){
  auto x = X<CuriousBase>{};
}
```

what are use cases for such a behaviour and what is the difference between this sample and the following  snippet?

```
template<class DerivedT>
struct CuriousBase{};

template<template<typename> typename... Features>
struct X : Features<X<Features...>> ... {
  X() = default;
  X(Features<X> ...f) : Features<X>(f)... {}
};

int main(){
  auto x = X<CuriousBase>{};
}
```

Both do compile but I thought, that one has to specify explicitly that X is itself a variadic class template but that does not seem to be necessary...

help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`X` is a [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name), so indeed `X` and `X<Features...>` are equivalent inside the class.

Comment: I see. thank you. So this is for the very same reasons why I dont need to repeat the template parameters of a class template when defining member functions of this class inside its scope, as opposed to defining them separately outside the class scope. there I have to prepend them before defining a member function. And what about my other question?

Comment: That is a *simple* constructor taking base classes to construct them.

Comment: yes I know, but in this specific case, I dont see any use, since upon construction of X I cannot pass lvalues of base classes to its constructor since those, as template classes, depend on their derived classes ; )

Comment: Since the class does nothing, hard to find a real use case for these constructor, `X<CuriousBase>{CuriousBase<X>{/*...*/}}` might be useful for more complicated `CuriousBase`.